# How to add 1920x1080 Display option and make it survive restart

Tags: display

I have elementary OS 5.1.5 Hera installed in VirtualBox 6.1.10. The display size 1920x1080 is not offered in the display settings. I have done the following to temporarily add the option.

In terminal I input:

```
sudo xrandr --newmode "1920x1080_60.00" 173.00 1920 2048 2248 2576 1080 1083 1088 1120 -hsync +vsync

sudo xrandr --addmode Virtual1 1920x1080_60.00
```

I used the display panel to select the new 1920x1080 option and everything looked just as expected. However, even after adding the code to .profile using:

```
gedit ~/.profile
```

[image]

The changes to the display settings did not survive a restart. How can I accomplish this? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I now have an answer to my own question. Being new to Linux I am still in the initial learning phase so I made a silly error. The first two code for "xranr newmode" & "xrandr addmode" are correct but I needed to create a new.sh file in  /etc/profile.d/

```
sudo gedit /etc/profile.d/external_monitor_resol.sh
```

into which the above newmode & addmode code is entered and the resulting file saved. In the end I now have 1920x1080 as an option in Displays and it survives restarts and shut downs.